# How to mock an imported constant with Jasmine?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jasmine

A component is meant to behave differently based on a external variable, which is used as a kind of configuration. I would like to test all the possible behaviors, but I don't get how to mock a constant variable.
I tried to use **spyOnProperty** as in the code below, but an error occurs, stating that the variable is not declared configurable.

```
// constants.js
export const DEFAULT_STATUS = 'test';

// component.spec.js
import * as constants from './constants';

// here other stuff and component init

it('should change default class based on a constant', () => {
    const tmpDefaultStatus = 'test1';
    spyOnProperty(constants, 'DEFAULT_STATUS', 'get').and.returnValue(tmpDefaultStatus);
    expect(component.className).toBe(tmpDefaultStatus)
});
```

Then this error is thrown:
*Error:  : DEFAULT_STATUS is not declared configurable*.

Is it still possible to mock that variable, without changing *constant.js* content?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is. I would do:

```
it('should change default class based on a constant', () => {
    const oldState = constants.DEFAULT_STATUS;
    const tmpDefaultStatus = 'test1';
    constants.DEFAULT_STATUS = tmpDefaultStatus;
    expect(component.className).toBe(tmpDefaultStatus);
    constants.DEFAULT_STATUS = oldState;
});
```

I am not sure if that test will pass or not but the idea is to change the value and take it back to its original for each test.

Comment: That kind of assignment is not possibile either, as DEFAULT_STATUS is a constant. I was looking for something like a getter inside _jest.mock_ for Jest.